# Vertical align text with image and horizontal image with image

Tags: html, css

1. I want to align text vertically with image such that text is on top of left image and below right image, AND
2. I want to center align left and right images with arrow character in the middle of images also center aligned

Images will probably not be of same size, one image may be taller then the other, and the text must not extend or overlap with the other image in this case. It should wrap.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

#name1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  float: left;
}

#name2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  float: right;
}

.image {
  max-width: 90px;
  max-height: 160px;
}

.arrow {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p id="name1">Boris</p>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <img class="image" src="https://www.kdnuggets.com/wp-content/uploads/tree-todd-quackenbush-unsplash.jpg"></img>
    <p class="arrow">→</p>
    <img class="image" src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000508491087-32hktm-t240x240.jpg"></img>
  </div>

  <p id="name2">asd</p>
</div>
```

You can find example here: https://jsfiddle.net/mj4kLcuo/

I have tried wrapping image and name into a column flex container but what that does is that the images are no longer center aligned, it looks like containers are now center aligned.

Comment: Just an aside, images close themselves with `/>`. There's no `</img>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using display: flex and flex-direction. You need also to change your HTML with a wrapping div around images and text. And as @j08691 said img tag just close itself . So if I correctly understood your need below is a proposition.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper-img1{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.wrapper-img2{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

#name1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  float: left;
}

#name2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  float: right;
}

.image {
  max-width: 90px;
  max-height: 160px;
}

.arrow {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="container">
    <div class="wrapper-img1">
      <p id="name1">Boris</p>
      <img class="image" src="https://www.kdnuggets.com/wp-content/uploads/tree-todd-quackenbush-unsplash.jpg"/>
    </div>
      <p class="arrow">→</p>
    <div class="wrapper-img2">
      <img class="image" src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000508491087-32hktm-t240x240.jpg"/>
      <p id="name2">asd</p>
    </div>   
  </div>
```